# CSS Animation works perfectly on one card, but not the other?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-animations

I have three cards where you can choose a subscription plan of your liking, its a frontendmentor.io (https://www.frontendmentor.io/challenges/pricing-component-with-toggle-8vPwRMIC) challenge that I want to add some extra animations on.

What I want to accomplish is: When I hover the left (first) card, I want it to slightly peek to the left and reveal more of itself. I do this by doubling the `padding-right` to `70` on that card. But that will push the other two cards to the right, I counter this by adding a `margin-right: 35px;` to the right (third) card. Then vice versa with the right card.

My problem is that when I hover the right (third) card it moves the other two cards no matter the amount of margin I add to the left (first) one. Suspecting this might have to do something with the parent div's or something. Any help is super appreciated!

Here's the parent .card-wrapper:

```css
.card-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 3px;
}


/* Here's the .card class: */

.card {
  padding: 35px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #BDD2B6;
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
}


/* Here's the animations:*/

.card:nth-child(1):hover {
  padding-right: 70px;
}

.card:nth-child(1):hover~.card:nth-child(3) {
  margin-right: 35px;
}

.card:nth-child(3):hover {
  padding-left: 70px;
}

.card:nth-child(3):hover~.card:nth-child(1) {
  margin-left: 35px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="card" id="card-basic">
    <h2>Basic</h2>
    <p class="price" id="title-basic">$19.99</p>
    <hr>
    <p>500 GB Storage</p>
    <hr>
    <p>2 Users Allowed</p>
    <hr>
    <p>Send up to 3 GB</p>
    <hr>
    <button class="btn1">LEARN MORE</button>
  </div>
  <div class="card" id="card-professional">
    <h2>Professional</h2>
    <p class="price" id="title-professional">$24.99</p>
    <hr>
    <p>1 TB Storage</p>
    <hr>
    <p>5 Users Allowed</p>
    <hr>
    <p>Send up to 10 GB</p>
    <hr>
    <button class="btn2">LEARN MORE</button>
  </div>
  <div class="card" id="card-master">
    <h2>Master</h2>
    <p class="price" id="title-master">$39.99</p>
    <hr>
    <p>2 TB Storage</p>
    <hr>
    <p>10 Users Allowed</p>
    <hr>
    <p>Send up to 20 GB</p>
    <hr>
    <button class="btn3">LEARN MORE</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

I hovered the third card, animation went through. Expected the other two cards to not move, but they still did.

Comment: Without your HTML we will only be guessing here methinks

Comment: you tried `:nth-child(even)` / `:nth-child(odd)` ?

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss was adding the cards html enough or should i add the whole html?

Comment: @imhvost Not sure how this could be applied? any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by "reveal more of itself" since it all already does show however to not effect the other cards you can just use a grid with a percent width for the columns and the animation will only effect the hovered card.

I added some style so the `<hr>` was visible instead of just being there.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.card-wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 33%);
  gap: 3px;
  background-color: #BDD2B622;
}

.card {
  /* Here's the .card class: */
  padding: 2em;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: top;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  border-radius: 0.625em;
  background-color: #BDD2B688;
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.card hr {
  display: block;
  height: 0.125em;
  background-color: #BDD2B6FF;
  border-color: #BDD2B6FF;
  width: 100%;
}


/* Here's the animations:*/

.card:nth-child(1):hover {
  padding-right: 4.375em;
}

.card:nth-child(1):hover~.card:nth-child(3) {
  margin-right: 2em;
}

.card:nth-child(3):hover {
  padding-left: 4.375em;
}

.card:nth-child(3):hover~.card:nth-child(1) {
  margin-left: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class='card-wrapper'>
  <div class="card" id="card-basic">
    <h2>Basic</h2>
    <p class="price" id="title-basic">$19.99</p>
    <hr>
    <p>500 GB Storage</p>
    <hr>
    <p>2 Users Allowed</p>
    <hr>
    <p>Send up to 3 GB</p>
    <hr>
    <button class="btn1" type="button">LEARN MORE</button>
  </div>
  <div class="card" id="card-professional">
    <h2>Professional</h2>
    <p class="price" id="title-professional">$24.99</p>
    <hr>
    <p>1 TB Storage</p>
    <hr>
    <p>5 Users Allowed</p>
    <hr>
    <p>Send up to 10 GB</p>
    <hr>
    <button class="btn2" type="button">LEARN MORE</button>
  </div>
  <div class="card" id="card-master">
    <h2>Master</h2>
    <p class="price" id="title-master">$39.99</p>
    <hr>
    <p>2 TB Storage</p>
    <hr>
    <p>10 Users Allowed</p>
    <hr>
    <p>Send up to 20 GB</p>
    <hr>
    <button class="btn3" type="button">LEARN MORE</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I found another workaround which was to add margin-right: -35px on the right card instead of adding margin-left: 35px to the left card. Still not sure why it behaves like this, but I really appreciate your help tho, you had a cool solution.